# PHP Viewing session in a table

Tags: php, session

Hello guys can you help I create a table which appears all the transaction of all user. Just like the pic. below

[image]

I want to view only specific user receiver transaction. When this user receiver login to his/her account for example when user receiver in transaction # 5 login to her account it will appear only those transaction of her.

Here's my code

```
$qry = "SELECT en.`transid`, en.`transdate`, 
                CONCAT(userlist.lname, ', ', userlist.fname, ' ', userlist.mname) AS sender_name, 
                CONCAT(userlist1.lname, ', ', userlist1.`fname`, ' ', userlist1.`mname`) AS receiver_name,
                en.`document_number`, doctype.`document_type`, vendor.`vendor_name`, acknowledge.`status_id`
                FROM `tbl_encode_transmittal` en 
                LEFT JOIN `tbl_acknowledgetransmittal` acknowledge ON en.`transid` = acknowledge.`transid`
                LEFT JOIN tbl_userlist userlist ON userlist.userid = en.sender_id
                LEFT JOIN tbl_userlist userlist1 ON userlist1.userid = en.`receiver_id`
                LEFT JOIN `tbl_doctype` doctype ON doctype.`doc_id` = en.`doctype_id`
                LEFT JOIN tbl_vendor vendor ON vendor.`vendor_id` =  en.vendor_id";
                WHERE userlist.userid = '" . $_SESSION['userid'] . "'";

        $res = mysql_query($qry) or die(mysql_error());
        echo "<tr>";
        while($row = mysql_fetch_array($res)){
                echo "<tr>";
                echo "<tbody>";
                echo "<td>" . $row['transid'] . "</td>";
                echo "<td>" . $row['transdate'] . "</td>";
                echo "<td>" . $row['sender_name'] . "</td>";
                echo "<td>" . $row['receiver_name'] . "</td>";
                echo "<td>" . $row['document_number'] . "</td>";
                echo "<td>" . $row['document_type'] . "</td>";
                echo "<td>" . $row['vendor_name'] . "</td>";
                echo "<td>" . $row['status'] . "</td>";
             }
```

Answer (score 0):

Change that first `echo <tr>` before the while loop to:

```
 echo "<table>";
```

Then after your while loop add:

```
 echo "</table>";
```

Answer (score 0):

Remove `";` which appear before where condition at last left join it may cause problem.

```
$qry = "SELECT en.`transid`, en.`transdate`, 
                CONCAT(userlist.lname, ', ', userlist.fname, ' ', userlist.mname) AS sender_name, 
                CONCAT(userlist1.lname, ', ', userlist1.`fname`, ' ', userlist1.`mname`) AS receiver_name,
                en.`document_number`, doctype.`document_type`, vendor.`vendor_name`, acknowledge.`status_id`
                FROM `tbl_encode_transmittal` en 
                LEFT JOIN `tbl_acknowledgetransmittal` acknowledge ON en.`transid` = acknowledge.`transid`
                LEFT JOIN tbl_userlist userlist ON userlist.userid = en.sender_id
                LEFT JOIN tbl_userlist userlist1 ON userlist1.userid = en.`receiver_id`
                LEFT JOIN `tbl_doctype` doctype ON doctype.`doc_id` = en.`doctype_id`
                LEFT JOIN tbl_vendor vendor ON vendor.`vendor_id` =  en.vendor_id
                WHERE userlist.userid = '" . $_SESSION['userid'] . "'";
```

Comment: if I remove the "; there will be no output.

Comment: did you get ` $_SESSION['userid'] ` check it and run your whole query in phpmyadmin and check weather you got your desired output or not.

Answer (score 0):

Your sql query is ok. I think you problem is the php syntax.

Here's the code:

```
$qry = "SELECT en.`transid`, en.`transdate`, 
            CONCAT(userlist.lname, ', ', userlist.fname, ' ', userlist.mname) AS sender_name, 
            CONCAT(userlist1.lname, ', ', userlist1.`fname`, ' ', userlist1.`mname`) AS receiver_name,
            en.`document_number`, doctype.`document_type`, vendor.`vendor_name`, acknowledge.`status_id`
            FROM `tbl_encode_transmittal` en 
            LEFT JOIN `tbl_acknowledgetransmittal` acknowledge ON en.`transid` = acknowledge.`transid`
            LEFT JOIN tbl_userlist userlist ON userlist.userid = en.sender_id
            LEFT JOIN tbl_userlist userlist1 ON userlist1.userid = en.`receiver_id`
            LEFT JOIN `tbl_doctype` doctype ON doctype.`doc_id` = en.`doctype_id`
            LEFT JOIN tbl_vendor vendor ON vendor.`vendor_id` =  en.vendor_id
            WHERE userlist1.userid = '" . $_SESSION['userid'] . "'";

    $res = mysql_query($qry) or die(mysql_error());
    echo "<table>";
    echo "<tbody>";
    while($row = mysql_fetch_array($res)){
        echo "<tr>";
        echo "<td>" . $row['transid'] . "</td>";
        echo "<td>" . $row['transdate'] . "</td>";
        echo "<td>" . $row['sender_name'] . "</td>";
        echo "<td>" . $row['receiver_name'] . "</td>";
        echo "<td>" . $row['document_number'] . "</td>";
        echo "<td>" . $row['document_type'] . "</td>";
        echo "<td>" . $row['vendor_name'] . "</td>";
        echo "<td>" . $row['status'] . "</td>";
        echo "</tr>";
    }
    echo "</tbody>";
    echo "<table>";
```

Comment: there will be no output @amrelnaggar.

Comment: Does the user id stored int `$_SESSION['userid']` has sent any transactions? Any way I just noticed that you want to show the received transactions only right? If so, replace `WHERE userlist.userid = '" . $_SESSION['userid'] . "'` with `WHERE userlist1.userid = '" . $_SESSION['userid'] . "'`

Comment: yes the user id stored has sent transactions. yes only received transaction I want to show. I already replace the code that you suggest but it doesn't show the output.

Answer (score 0):

Here's my table code

```
<table>
    <tr>
        <thead>
        <th>Transmittal #</th>
        <th>Transmittal Date</th>
        <th>Sender Name</th>
        <th>Department</th>
        <th>Invoice #</th>
        <th>Document Type</th>
        <th>Vendor Name</th>
        <th>Remark</th>
        <th>Action</th>
        </thead>
    </tr>

        <?php
            include('connection.php');

            $sql = "SELECT en.transid, en.transdate, CONCAT(userlist.lname, ', ', userlist.fname, ' ', userlist.mname) AS sender_name,userlist.department,
                    userlist.department, CONCAT(userlist1.lname, ', ', userlist1.`fname`, ' ', userlist1.`mname`) AS receiver_name,
                    vendor.`vendor_name`, doctype.document_type, doctype.document_description, en.`remarks`
                    FROM tbl_encode_transmittal en
                    LEFT JOIN tbl_vendor vendor ON vendor.`vendor_id` =  en.vendor_id
                    LEFT JOIN tbl_doctype doctype ON doctype.`doc_id` = en.doctype_id
                    LEFT JOIN tbl_userlist userlist ON userlist.userid = en.sender_id
                    LEFT JOIN tbl_userlist userlist1 ON userlist1.userid = en.`receiver_id`
                    WHERE userlist.userid = '" . $_SESSION['userid'] . "'";

            $rs = mysql_query($sql) or die(mysql_error());

            while($row = mysql_fetch_array($rs)){
                echo "<tr>";
                echo "<tbody>";
                echo "<td>" . $row['transid'] . "</td>";
                echo "<td>" . $row['transdate'] . "</td>";
                echo "<td>" . $row['sender_name'] . "</td>";
                echo "<td>" . $row['department'] . "</td>";
                echo "<td>" . $row['document_num'] . "</td>";
                echo "<td>" . $row['document_type'] . "</td>";
                echo "<td>" . $row['vendor_name'] . "</td>";
                echo "<td>" . $row['remarks'] . "</td>";
            } ?>
        </tbody>
    </tr>
</table>
```